# Focus sibling window in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window, focus

I've got an application which has several child windows. For user experience reasons, sometimes we want to re-use these windows instead of always opening new ones. So the main window has two child windows, A and B. The user is using Child A. As a result of their action in Child A, we wish to focus Child B and perform an action on it.

I have complete control of the source for all windows involved.

Unfortunately, it seems like Child A no longer has the right to focus Child B in Chrome. The main window can give it focus, but only if it has focus, and the user is using Child A. Therefore there seems to be no way for Child A to grant Child B focus unless we somehow roundtrip focus through the parent window, messing up the window order, e.g. Child A would then be last in the order instead of underneath Child B.

I have tried to fix this by simply having all three windows involved attempt to focus Child B, but none of them can.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same issue and this is working fine in IE11 and Firefox but looks like chromium has the issue.

Bug has been entered to chrome, please stared this bug for your track.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1286348